# Magento2 install stuck on file permissions

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, installation, setup, sample-data

I am using a fresh version of Magento 2.1
Apache 2.2
I have set my file permissions to 777 on the entire folder
I can see that Apache is writing as apache:apache
I have chown'd the entire folder to apache:apache

This spins

[image]

Finally it ends up like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the write permission again, recursively (a.k.a. `chmod -R +w pub`).

Magento checks if **ALL** files inside those paths are writable, not just the main directories. My guess is that Magento wants to be sure it can clean it up afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes from the `filePermissionsAction` method of the `setup/src/Magento/Setup/Controller/Environment.php` action class: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/feeadbe7351647e2edca646c04a03ddeb20f922a/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Controller/Environment.php#L160

It's hard to say what went wrong here but I suggest you debug by checking the content of the `$requiredPaths` and `$currentPaths` variables.